# Read browser history from client side

Tags: javascript, browser-history

Is it possible to read browser history from client side using JavaScript? If not, any other signed/unsigned plugins that can do it?

Thanks

Comment: check this::http://www.stevenyork.com/tutorial/getting_browser_history_using_javascript

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides in-built object called as history, you can read the length, back, forward, go and other properties as well.